# Image fill is not working properly

Tags: css

This is my html code

```
<div class="feature-image">
    <a class="featured_image_link" href="#">
        <img src="1.jpg">
    </a>                    
</div>
```

My image 1.jpg size is `150px x 150px` and i have mentioned in the css as

```
.feature-image{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    display:block; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.feature-image img{
    position:absolute; 
    top:-50; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%;
}
```

I know that when i give different image size (for eg: `300x200` or `600x350` etc) the image will fill inside that `150x150` and not stretches.

But actually its not working properly. Please help whether there is any mistake in this code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/49zhd/1/ Check this fiddle n tell us what exactly is not working

Comment: I have seen in jsfiddle that the image fills according to the size of the image and not in 150 x 150 size. Thats the question. I need any of the size should fill in that 150x150 size. Is there any solution?

Comment: Check my solution and check the full explanation

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Let me explain how this work.

First things first. Your CSS has a bug.

```
top:-50;
```

This wont do anything. It has to be something like

```
top:-50px;
```

But my question is why do you want negative margins? it will only hide you image by 50 pixels on the top side.

Ok, now coming to the real issue. You say you have no problems when your Image is `150X150` pixels. Thats because the parent `<div>` is `150x150`. But if you have a different image size like `300x200` you have a problem.

This happens because in your CSS you have only mentioned `width: 100%` for the image.From here on its plain math.

The width=300 & height =200
Since you have mentioned `width:100%` the image automatically gets adjusted to the new width

```
300(original width)/150(new width)=2

So taking the same factor of 2
200(original height)/2=100(new height)
```

Hence you **rendered** image will have height of **100px**.

if you want the rendered image to have same height of div just add this line to img CSS

```
height: 100%;
```

***[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49zhd/2/)***

Comment: Hey after putting height: 100%; it works fine for me. Thank You. This what i am asking for. Once again Thank you. @marsone

Comment: @user2644743, remember that this will strech the image incase the original image is not a square. ex, if orignal image is 400x400 then there will not be an issue, but an image like 400*200 will look a but funny. Hope you understand

Comment: Also if my solution worked for you, dont forget to mark it as answer. :)

Comment: Oh, in this case whether there is any solution for cropping the image to that 150 x 150 size automatically by using css. So that i think it would be enough perfect. Am i right?

Comment: @C-Link, because there is nothing specified at end. Like -50px or -50%

Answer (score -1):

from the code you have pasted, it's working properly. Are you able to link to the site where this is live and not working? Cache issue?

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FNQZn/

```
.feature-image {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.feature-image img {
    position:absolute;
    top:-50;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: How is this a solution. its good that you made a fiddle but its just the same code the the OP has posted. How does this qualify as a solution. Where does 'cache' come into the picture

Comment: jsfiddle link needs to be acompanied by code, so all I did was copy and paste his working code. 

i'm saying that in his live environment or on the website he is working on, he might need to refresh his cache as what he posted works perfectly.

Comment: what this then -> top:-50; ? its there in your fiddle.

Comment: perhaps you are not reading what i'm saying. All I'm trying to say is that there is nothing wrong with his code. From his code, his image should fill within the box of 150x150

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what the OP is looking for here? he says somethings not working. Can u tell me what he means by not working?